# performance problem, code works but consider takes long time in long list

Tags: python, list, performance, set, iteration

why the following code is consider inefficient in terms of time complexity and how can I improve it? The time complexity for ia in n takes o(n) hence the problem.

what have I tired? I sorted initially n,a and b but no change in performance.

Objective, find the sum of h-m
Note:  len(a) always equal to len(b)

```
n=[1, 5, 3] #//can be with 100K+ items
a=set([3,1]) #//can be with 50K+ items
b=set([5,7])

h=0
m=0
for ia, ib in zip(a,b):
    if ia in n:
        h+=1
    if ib in n:
        m+=1

print (h-m)
```

Edit: I realized that the it is insufficient to discuss only concept ideas such as why it is consider inefficient without explicitly address time/space complexity. I have changed the question accordingly.

Comment: "Why the following code is consider inefficient" By whom? Who told you this? What happens when you try running the code - did you try to give it large inputs? How long does it take to run when you give it large inputs? How long is it expected/required to take? "Why the following code is consider inefficient" What does this mean? Conceptually, what do those variables represent? What is the **purpose** of this calculation? What is the **meaning** of the input, and of the output?

Comment: `if ia in n` Testing for membership in a large list is slow, because it has to check each element in the list sequentially.  Can `n` be a set instead of a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `n` is a `list`, and it's *huge* (100K+ items), each `if WHATEVER in n:` is doing `O(n)` work, involving 100K+ equality checks.

You basically have your types backwards here; you're using `set`s for things you iterate (where being a `set` is saving you little aside from perhaps removing duplicates from your inputs) and using `list`s for things you membership test (where `O(n)` containment checks are *much* more expensive on large `list`s than `O(1)` containment checks are for `set`s of any size).

Assuming the elements of `n` are hashable, convert them to a `set` before the loop and use containment tests against the `set`:

```
n=[1, 5, 3] #can be with 100K+ items
nset = set(n)   # Cache set view of n
a=set([3,1]) #can be with 50K+ items
b=set([5,7])

h=0
m=0
for ia, ib in zip(a,b):
    if ia in nset:  # Check against set in O(1)
        h+=1
    if ib in nset:  # Check against set in O(1)
        m+=1

print (h-m)
```

Note that `zip`ing is doing nothing except possibly excluding some elements from being iterated at all; if `len(a) != len(b)`, you'll fail to check the elements that would be iterated beyond the length of the shortest `set`. If you want to count them all, the simplest solution is to split the loops replacing the single loop with just:

```
h = sum(1 for ia in a if ia in nset)  # sum(ia in nset for ia in a) also works, but it's somewhat slower/less intuitive
m = sum(1 for ib in b if ib in nset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Speculating, the `if x in y` test is slowest. It probably doesn't help much to have a and b as sets - you're just zipping and enumerating. But if n was a set, then the membership test would likely be faster.

It's probably not necessary to zip, given that you don't appear to be doing anything with ia and ib such that they interact, but I doubt that that introduces much overhead.

Comment: you're right! I should have taken this approach initially. Say would you mind uprd my answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way - using `set.intersection` - and without using a `for` loop or `zip` function:

```py
n = [1, 5, 3]  # can be with 100K+ items
a = {3, 1}  # can be with 50K+ items
b = {5, 7}

nset = set(n)  # cache set view of n

h = len(nset & a)
m = len(nset & b)

print(h - m)
```